# Update ngRepeat array based on select input

Tags: angularjs

Angular.js is driving me crazy, Ben Nadel's [angular.js roller coster](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2439-my-experience-with-angularjs-the-super-heroic-javascript-mvw-framework.htm) is probably what's keeping me sane!

Let's say we have this basic controller:

```
function ResultsCtrl($scope) {$scope.results = {
'Autumn 2011': {
     'Courses': [{code: 'GS515', 'grade': 80}, {code: 'GS505', 'grade': 60}],
     'Statistics': [{}]
               },
'Autumn 2012': {}/*SIMILAR DATA STRUCTURE*/
$scope.selectedPeriod = 'Autumn 2011';/*FOR INITIALISING THE DATA*/
};
```

Then in the `html` code, `ng-repeat` is used on an array based on a selection:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="ResultsCtrl">
    <div>
        <select ng-options="period as period for (period, result) in results" ng-model="selectedPeriod"></select>
    </div>
     <div ng-repeat="course in results['{{selectedPeriod}}']['Courses']">
        <p>Course: {{ course.code }}, Grade: {{ course.grade }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above was my first approach, then I tried hard coding the array in `ng-repeat` to see where the problem is and it worked fine: `<div ng-repeat="course in results['Autumn 2011']['Courses']">`. The next approach tried using the controller to select the array. this was added to the script: `$scope.periodResults = $scope.results[$scope.selectedPeriod]['Courses'];` and `periodResults` was used for `ng-repeat` but it didn't work, the default array was loaded correctly but the `<select>` tag had no effect.

I have seen questions and blog posts about similar problems but they didn't help. All had something to do with `$scope.apply()` or `$timeout` which I didn't understand.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right fiddle?

Comment: I removed the fiddle, it was indeed wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing a closing brace for $scope.results:

```
function ResultsCtrl($scope) {$scope.results = {
'Autumn 2011': {
     'Courses': [{code: 'GS515', 'grade': 80}, {code: 'GS505', 'grade': 60}],
     'Statistics': [{}]
               },
'Autumn 2012': {}/*SIMILAR DATA STRUCTURE*/
} /* this closing brace was missing */
$scope.selectedPeriod = 'Autumn 2011';/*FOR INITIALISING THE DATA*/
};
```

And in your template, you were incorrectly using an angular expression when referring to your selectedPeriod model. Here's how your template should look:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="ResultsCtrl">
    <div>
        <select ng-options="period as period for (period, result) in results" ng-model="selectedPeriod"></select>
    </div>
     <div ng-repeat="course in results[selectedPeriod]['Courses']">
        <p>Course: {{ course.code }}, Grade: {{ course.grade }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the use of [selectedPeriod] instead of ['{{selectedPeriod}}'] like you had in your code.

Comment: Simple but awesome!, Thanks a lot.